# Why use an ordered list for an html form to improve accessibility?

Tags: html, forms, accessibility

Why would you use an ordered list within a form to improve accessibility?

Comment: Where do you take this idea from? I saw very **few** forms using such design.

Comment: Can you provide a/some example(s)?

Comment: I didn't know most html forms used lists at all...

Comment: well just look at every form creating tutorial, and they always use ol tags to organize form content

Comment: like this one:http://www.alistapart.com/articles/prettyaccessibleforms/

Comment: @dave - Probably unwittingly, your original question was not really accurate, so I edited it to communicate the actual question of why that tutorial uses ordered lists. In reality, it is not common at all, AFAIK.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may want to checkout the 'A List Apart' article on [Prettier Accessible Forms](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/prettyaccessibleforms) which goes into some details as to why ordered lists are used in many forms.

It is mainly to do with screen readers "Additionally, the ol provides additional information for some screen readers that announce the number of list-items when they first encounter the list."

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily `<ol>` but `<ul>` can also prove useful - as it adds additional context and acts as a delighter as the screen-reader will announce up front the number of list items - regardless of it being ordered or not.

Having said that, it's a fairly minimal improvement as many disabled users will navigate in forms mode and discover the input fields like that. It is miles more important to have your form fields accessible and semantically correct, than putting them in `<li>` tags, so do focus on that first.